# how to read all values from the registry

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, registry

what i am trying to do is to have multiple
user names and folder paths in one key.

so i have this structure

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
>
> -- SOFTWARE
>
> -- XYZ
>
> -- userDB

now in userDB i have the info like this

```
> NAME    TYpe   Data
> 
> Admin  Reg_sz  C:\Desktop
> 
> Admin2 REG_SZ  C:\xyz\logs
```

how can i read the values in userDB...

any suggestions.. thanks

i tried this code:

```
            RegistryKey masterKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\xyz");
        if (masterKey == null)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Null Masterkey!");
        }
        else
        {

            table.Rows.Add(false, masterKey.GetValue("userDB"), DateTime.Now);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = table;
            //Console.WriteLine("MyKey = {0}", masterKey.GetValue("userDB"));
        }
        masterKey.Close();
```

but i get the error
Access to the registry key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\xyz' is denied.

Comment: Your tags are a bit strange. Is your project WinForms or asp.net? And how is this related to regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you talk about reading values in your topic, your code actually writes to the registry.

You can't write to most of the `HKLM` part of the registry by default as a limited user. A limited users may not destroy/manipulate these keys because that's a security risk.

You could have your setup program(running with admin privs) change the permissions for your shared registry key. But that's bad style, and I wouldn't do it.

When using asp.net there might be additional restrictions related to the medium trust model.

You have:

```
RegistryKey masterKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\xyz");
```

[RegistryKey.CreateSubKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ad51f2dx.aspx) is documented as:

> Creates a new subkey or opens an existing subkey for write access.

Opening for write access most likely requires write privileges.

[`RegistryKey.OpenSubKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9f66s0a.aspx) is used to open a key for read access. So it most likely requires no writing privileges.

Comment: `RegistryKey masterKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\xyz");` How is that commented out?

Comment: sorry my bad i did not see that

Comment: i am not getting the permissin error now.. but my main problem to read the values from userDB i still cant figure out. how do i read all the valus in one time and put them in a list?? please help.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

At which point are you getting access denied? Are you running this code elevated or as administrator?

Chances are you are failing when calling CreateSubKey(), which when writing to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE requires elevated permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I think Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\xyz") would try to open the key with write access if that key exists.

Try to open the key with read access instead.
I think that you can use CreateSubKey(String, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck) instead to specify permission access.

For more information, please refer to MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411617.aspx